# How to create a page bookmark option in android?

Tags: android

I was creating a Book & Reference application in android (Tax and Investment Law book), but I wanna add some options in it. I want to provide an option to all users allowing them to bookmark any page they want. Thanks for your answer in advance :)

Comment: You can set flage(boolean value) for bookmark for every page in Database and display according it ... Additionally change flage value for page while add/remove bookmarks.

Comment: BlackTiger, Can you be more specific or can you provide me some coding?